# How do I create an android phone app?

Tags: android

what software do I need to create an android app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest method: [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/index.html).

The SDK will install components for Eclipse, including an Android emulator for debugging, and you do your development in Java.

**Edit**: [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) has since been released, and is likely the preferred route for development going forward.

Answer (score 3):

You should start at http://developer.android.com/, there is a wealth of information for getting started, what software to use and code samples etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the correct series of 1's and 0's, such that the android device in question  does what you want. It will be a bit easier if you first Google something like "android development" though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) - just Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola packages lots of stuff with its free MotodevStudio (just need to create an account on motorola). Maybe easier than setting up your own Eclipse + Android SDK and it works for eveery Android phone, not just Motorola's.

Else also apply for an account on the Google tool AppInventor